# productFlavours and packages in android

Tags: java, android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, android-productflavors

I have been watching a tutorial on productFlavors feature of android studio, I really felt it messy and I come up with some question,

1) Okay I understand the buildtypes whatever the module, you have 2 build types release and debug, we can configure release and we dont need to configure debug as its config by default and if we have to do we can and start with initWith and what the heck is jnidebug, is it something else other than debug?

2) They added productFlavors in gradle script and inside 2 flavor and inside each flavor a package name with .flavorName and after that they created two packages with same name as main, why not same package name as we declare in each flavor of productFlavor? like com.example.xx.flavor1 and com.example.xx.flavor2?
why same package name as main also what is the purpose of applicationIDSuffix here?

3) Then they created two classes in each flavor and accessing its method in mainActivity.java of main folder, can we inverse it like can we take method in flavours.java from mainActivity.java, and what if we have different package name, would the method of mainActivity still be available in each flavours.javas?

Answer (score 0):

Lot's of details for your questions could be found on this page: [Gradle Definitions and Configurations](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/index.html#build-config). But with further clarifications of your questions I could improve the answer to suite your question.

For question 1: I'm not sure where jnidebug came from. Could be folder and part of a source set.

For question 2: productFlavor are to create different apps but with the same code base. For example one would create two versions of the app, let's say a **free** version and a **paid** version, the **free** version contains implementations to show ads but the **paid** version doesn't. To do that, the **free** version contains layout and logic code different than the **paid** version. However both would be sharing the same `main` base code. Furthermore, some apps with different flavors might both need to be installed on Android such that they co-exist. To have that they should have different application IDs, otherwise Android would overwrite the first installed flavored app with the second one. To have that, the developer would create a base a application ID (most of the times it would be similar to `com.example.app`). And then within the flavor config, the developer would set the `applicationIDSuffix` to resemble the flavor in order to get Android to install both apps. Let's say we have to flavors, **base** and **extended**, and within the `build.gradle` the **extended** has the `applicationIDSuffix '.extended'` set. When the two flavors are compiled and built, there will be two apps, the **base** with the application ID of `com.example.app`, and the **extended** with `com.example.app.extended`. Hence Android will install both without any issues.

For question 3: Of course! And be careful, although there would be different apps with different application IDs, their code would have the same package name. Code package name and application IDs are different and not related to each other, although most of the times they are the same. What happens at compile time is gradle would merge the codes from flavors with `main` and compile them under the same package name, for example `com.example.app`. But the `AndroidManifest.xml` would be contain the application ID of the flavor settings that you've chosen to compile, like `com.example.app.flavor` in case the `applicationIDSuffix '.flavor'` is set.

Comment: Can we put existing testing package name in productflavours so that we can have apk of existing testing package? like when we create new product we see 3 package name 1 for source code and other 2 for testing

Comment: Testing is another story with gradle and productFlavors but yes. You could have the base testing code within the main test folders (by default they are two: test and androidTest), these will be always available with any flavor, and then also have specific test folders and code for the specific flavors which are merged with main test packages/code when compiling and building a selected flavor. To better understand it, checkout source sets in this link: https://developer.android.com/studio/build/build-variants.html#sourcesets